# Books giving a high-level overview of software testing?

Tags: learning

I'm kind of new to software testing. I'm like a first-year student in computer programming who is not familiar with the testing field. So I'm looking for a few books that would give a high-level overview of this field as opposed to diving into a lot of details. (Maybe a book for business people or Managers as opposed to geeks and engineers.)

Could you please introduce me to some of these types of books?

Comment: If you want an overview of software testing or development, you could do worse than to start with the Wiki articles on the topics. They give a starting point for people with no experience. You may also find that as your course progresses you'll gain more of an idea of what the field is like.

Comment: Do you want to learn programming (if so, Python is widely considered as best language for beginners), or do you want to understand what object-oriented approach is (design patterns are specific tricks in OO to solve common situations)

Comment: I know  C a little bit. but I see my colleagues talking about differences among the way e.x C defines tables vs. Pyton or Java... They have a broad idea about programming language. maybe they are not anymore capable to code in any of these languages, but they still remember the essence of each language and its limitations.

Comment: Please don't tell me that wiki is good for a novice like me. I remember once trying to find out the differences between a controller and a driver and i put hours and hours on wiki's technical words. finanly i figured out that one is a piece of code and the other is a material (physically exists !!!!

Comment: How Do You Eat An Elephant?: One Bite at a Time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I highly recommend "Lessons Learned in Software Testing" by Bret Pettichord, Cem Kaner, and James Bach. In my opinion, this is the best book for an overview of software testing, without digging in too deeply.

I have a review on my blog: http://www.allthingsquality.com/2011/12/book-lessons-learned-in-software.html

When you have finished this one, you can find some others here: http://www.allthingsquality.com/search/label/Books.

I'd recommend "Perfect Software: And Other Illusions about Testing" by Gerald M. Weinberg for your second read.

You will have read some of the classic books by some of the well-known experts in the field. Not a bad start...

Answer (score 3):

> So i'm looking for a book in this field which doesn't go into the
>   details, but give me an insight about many things in this field.(Maybe
>   a book for commercials or Managers and not for geeks and engineers.)

I would recommend Gerald Weinberg's [Perfect Software: And Other Illusions about Testing](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0932633692) for a few reasons:

1. It explains what we should expect from testing, what are the main challenges are, and what is wrong with common practices and attitudes from high level:

   - For example, Weinberg explains the impossibility of complete testing in an easy to understand manner
   - That fact it covers very basic concepts and misconceptions in a high level way is reason enough for managers (or anyone else who hasn't been a tester) to read it
2. Is relatively easy to read (not very technical; not programmatic)
3. It's only about 200 pages, so it's a relatively short read

If Perfect Software is too high-level than I'd recommend checking out Cem Kaner's [Foundations of Software Testing Workbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0989811921). It's not as comprehensive as his older book [Testing Computer Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471358460) but it's more relevant and up to date.

(I see that Joe also mentioned this book but I'm attempting to explain why this book among all the other is probably the best choice. )

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of really good books out there for software testing, my favorite book that I have read so far would be **Agile Testing: A Practical Guide for Testers and Agile Teams** by *Lisa Crispin, and Janet Gregory* here is the amazon book link Click [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321534468)!

This book covers a lot of really great Agile testing methodologies and material, if you are unaware of **Agile testing**; I really suggest that you look into it! The industry is really heavy into the idea of agile development and it is a valuable asset to a company to have people who know how to use it effectively.

Here is another link to a list of good software testing books: http://www.fromdev.com/2012/04/8-best-software-testing-books-every-qa.html

For programming books, that is a little more difficult. I would learn what your company is currently using, or technologies that you are interested in and go from there. Usually you need to have a language in mind so you can grab a beginners book an start from there. Personally I started with C# with the book **C# Primer Plus** by *Klaus Michelsen* here is the amazon book link Click [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672321521)!

You didn't specify whether or not the books should be free, so I just suggested what I have used personally. Take a look, and hopefully that answers your question.

Comment: I'm not very familair with Agile testing. If the book you proposed is just about Agile, it won't help me. I want one which talks about V cycle as well for example. I don't want a book in a special field. but a general one a bit like a dictioanry. I'm gonna take a look at it anyway.    I know a bit of C, and C++ but can't distinguish the idea behind them, so i look at them the same way !

Comment: @Michelle I am still going to recommend that book for agile testing, it's not all about agile testing; more about best practices. I don't know of a testing book that is like a dictionary, and don't think there is one out there like that. Look at the others on the link below my agile book recommendation those could be more appealing. There are a lot of difference between those two languages, and they are not necessarily what I would recommend starting with; but if you have knowledge of them grab a book on it and go with it!

Comment: This is my bible since since the day I started reading it.  Most companies (in recent surveys) are doing Agile now.  This is the clearest guide to me on what to do.  Hundreds of real world examples from experience and a chapter format that is a pleasure to experience.  I've trained folks using this book, a chapter a week.

Answer (score 1):

"The Art of Software Testing" by Glenford Myers has been a staple for over 25 years. The middle chapters do go into details of testing but at a high level. It has also been updated for Agile and Mobile in the third edition.

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be  "Lessons Learned in Software Testing" by Bret Pettichord, Cem Kaner, and James Bach.  When I moved from dev to testing this was the first book I bought and I've lent it to many new testers since then.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look into [software testing by ron patton](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Software_Testing.html?id=MTEiAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y).

Its good for new commers in testing field.